# Questions about Endogeneity and IVs

Tags: least-squares, instrumental-variables, endogeneity, hausman

I am doing the returns of education on earnings.  I have education (number of years of edu) as my endogenous variable and I am using Father Education as an instrument.
I am using SAS and I ran a 2sls.  I used the first stage to test for endogeneity by grabbing the residuals and adding it to the original model (Hausman Test).  The coefficient on the first stage residual ended up not being significant.  I am not sure where to go from here.  Does this mean that I should just use OLS?  Are there other methods to test/identify endogeneity?